# Where can I find a graph of Bitcoin value vs USD for over 60 days?

Tags: charts, value

[Bitcoin Charts](http://bitcoincharts.com/markets/mtgoxUSD.html) seems to only offer graphs of up to 60 days.

Comment: This is a straight dupe of http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/748/where-can-i-get-raw-data-series-of-bitcoin-prices .  Although this one came first, that one is a marginally better question, so I suggest merging this one into that.

Comment: @eMansipater - this is not a dup. In that later question I asked for raw data. Here I asked for a graph.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bitcoin Charts currently have charts of up to a year in length, as well as "all data" charts.

Example 360 days:

http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/mtgoxUSD#rg360zvztgSzm1g10zm2g25

Comment: I actually found that page once, just forgot that it's there (it's easy to miss it). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can see further back in Bitcoin Charts
http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/mtgoxUSD#vztgSzm1g10zm2g25

Answer (score 1):

try www.btcdb.net or www.bitcoindashboard.com for detailed informations...

Answer (score 0):

https://bitcoinhelp.net/know/more/price-chart-history

Has a chart containing:

- average daily BTC/USD prices starting from 2009
- annotated historical events
- optional logarithmic scale

Answer (score -1):

http://bitcoinity.org/markets?theme=light

this is a great site too, but i believe it only goes to 30 days
this is a live graph though

Answer (score -1):

TRy this chart , also look at litecoin, the next bitcoin, @ $3. now with $55 M in the market cap. http://coinmarketcap.com/