# Where can I get historic data series of Bitcoin prices?

Tags: exchange-rate, historical-trade-data

Where can I get a time series of (date, bitcoin price in USD)? BitcoinCharts no longer provide historic data, only the last 20,000 samples.

Comment: Stephen Gornick has a very useful summary of the price history at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmcTCtjBoRWUdHJuUE1mUkFxa3A0eHBDQkxZLVVFZmc#gid=0.

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22989/where-can-i-get-tick-by-tick-historical-btc-price-data

Answer (score 16):

EDIT: These links appear to no longer work

---

You can get it at [Bitcoincharts](http://bitcoincharts.com/about/markets-api/):

```
http://bitcoincharts.com/t/trades.csv?symbol=SYMBOL[&start=UNIXTIME][&end=UNIXTIME]
```

It returns a CSV file with the format:`unixtime,price,amount`.

For example, you can use this link to get the MtGox prices since August:

```
http://bitcoincharts.com/t/trades.csv?symbol=mtgoxUSD&start=1312174800
```

Comment: Awsome. I used this link to get data from 2009. http://bitcoincharts.com/t/trades.csv?symbol=mtgoxUSD&start=1252402936

Comment: Well, this turned out absolutely meaningless. Here is the ugly conversation script if anyone's interested: https://gist.github.com/1251429

Comment: see my answer to get all trades as one big file

Comment: The links in this answer have stopped working.

Answer (score 5):

You can download the whole historical data **(every single trade)** from the various exchanges **as a single .csv file** here:

http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/

Answer (score 4):

Try [quandl](http://www.quandl.com/)!
and search for "bitcoin"

for example:
http://www.quandl.com/BITCOIN-Bitcoin-Charts/MTGOXUSD-Bitcoin-Markets-mtgoxUSD

Answer (score 2):

You didn't state what format you are looking for. Investing.com has a decent tool for this. I've used it for calculating long term gains/losses.

https://www.investing.com/currencies/btc-usd-historical-data

EDIT:
Your updated question asked for JSON. 
I would use blockchain.info

`https://api.blockchain.info/charts/market-price?format=json&timespan=all`

Other timespan options:

`&timespan=30days`
`&timespan=60days`
`&timespan=180days`
`&timespan=1year`
`&timespan=2years`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just updated it with the format.

Comment: Answer updated with JSON example

Comment: I've merged the question into this one, this answer may require small edits to make it fit in :)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try http://www.cryptodatasets.com/ It has free raw(every trade by trade) data and sampled data from Bitfinex and HitBtc (non from MtGox since its not operating anymore).

P.S. it's my website

Comment: nice site, why not compress the csv with gzip?

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoincharts recently retricted the download for latest 20000 trades, it basically represents only two days of tick data.

Guys, if you have downloaded it before the restriction, would you mind sharing those past tick data? It would help me a lot.
Thanks!

**Update:**

As promised, I'm sharing the way how I downloaded all historical trade-by-trade data from MtGox. Firstly, register at BigQuerry cloud database, at this time only download of 16k rows of data is enabled. Secondly go to bitbucket.org/nitrous/bq and download the software which automatize the data download. The whole database took approx one hour to download. Everything is free, no charges. Enjoy!

Comment: Just realised I post a question as an answer - sorry!

Comment: See Meni's comment above. I have unaccepted the accepted answer, because it's, as you say, no longer correct. I personally don't have historic price data, but perhaps you can post on bitcointalk.org and ask there. (please post here if you find it!)

Comment: Meni has only end-of-day data which is not sufficient. However, I will do as you suggested and ask on bitcointalk. If I find any, surely I will post it here for others!

Comment: As promised, I'm sharing the way how I downloaded all historical trade-by-trade data from MtGox. Firstly, register at BigQuerry cloud database, at this time only download of 16k rows of data is enabled. Secondly go to https://bitbucket.org/nitrous/bq and download the software which automatize the data download. The whole database took approx one hour to download. Everything is free, no charges. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks! I updated your answer with the content of your comment.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=218980.0) explains how to get a dump of past Mt Gox data and the [Mt Gox API](https://bitbucket.org/nitrous/mtgox-api/overview) allows current data. Hope this helps!

Comment: A bit outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are websites to do that.

- [coincap.io](https://coincap.io)
- [coinmarketcap.com](https://coinmarketcap.com) (Most used)
- [bitinfocharts.com](https://bitinfocharts.com) (Most advanced)

Comment: This answer has been moved due to questions being merged, please double check it doesn't need any edits :)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.CryptoDataDownload.com is newer but has 28+ exchanges, ~550 pairs, 8+ ccy pairs, and daily/hourly/minute timeframes to download via csv format for free

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation or this will be deleted as spam :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from http://www.coinintraday.com . It offers many intraday data