# Where can I download BTC historical ticker data?

Tags: exchange-rate, raw-data, historical-trade-data, live-data

Where can I download historical data for Bitcoin price for mtgox?

In this 2 Year old thread:
[Where can I get historic data series of Bitcoin prices?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/748/where-can-i-get-historic-data-series-of-bitcoin-prices)

The described solution is as follows:
download this tool and use it:
https://bitbucket.org/nitrous/bq

The problem is the tool only downloads data until 12.03.2013

Can someone explain to me what I need to do to get the data after this date. 
Does someone have this data and could upload it or knows where to download the data?

Comment: [This answer](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/13194/9175) to the linked question is still valid.

Comment: Unless you Know/can tell me a way how to get the data till today i would not see this as an valid answer. The last day this download produces is 9 months old.

Comment: Go to http://www.quandl.com/BITCOIN-Bitcoin-Charts/MTGOXUSD-Bitcoin-Markets-mtgoxUSD, select the desired time span (default is from 2010-07-17 to today), click download, choose file format. This is what I get: http://pastebin.com/ED0Dt2sH

Comment: As i wrote I'm looking for TICKDATA not Daily. quandl is absolute NO solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can get complete and up-to-date price history here:

http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/mtgoxUSD.csv

You can also get subsets of the data.
For details see: http://bitcoincharts.com/about/markets-api/

Comment: Interesting link. Only problem it only has data back till 10th of June 2011. The first trades on Mtgox startet at 17. July 2010. But i can maybe combine this with some other data i found. I will post here how to do it if i find a way. Thanks for input so far.

Comment: Are you sure that these are actual transactions and not just "cherry picks"? Moreover, it would be great if each entry mentioned whether this is a `buy` or `sell` transaction.

Comment: Hi Tom, what do you mean with "Cherry picks" got curious...

Comment: Thanks for original answer. I use this link http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/bitstampUSD.csv.gz

Answer (score 1):

You can download BTC ticker data for February 2014 there

http://btce-alert.com/files/BTC_USD_ticker_data_february2014.csv

Answer (score 0):

If you have a WP site you can download the [99bitocins ticker](http://wordpress.org/plugins/bitcoin-ticker-widget/).