# Where can I get tick by tick historical BTC volume data?

Tags: historical-trade-data

Related to [Where can I get tick by tick historical BTC price data?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22989/where-can-i-get-tick-by-tick-historical-btc-price-data) but I need volume data in association with price for all the time tick by tick

Thanks!

Comment: Volume is much harder to get accurately because the volume of transactions outside of official exchanges is unknown. Whenever bitcoins are sent from one address to another, they might be part of a transaction which involves Fiat currency as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using Poloniex API to get it.

https://poloniex.com/support/api/

Answer (score 2):

Try https://tardis.dev it provides tick by tick BTC trade data you can use to calculate volume.

P.S it's my website.

Answer (score 2):

[FirstRateData](https://firstratedata.com/i/crypto/BTC/tick) has prices and volumes, aggregated across 10 exchanges back to 2013 for Bitcoin and back to 2017 for 50 other crypto tickers.

For more complete coverage,  [Kaiko](https://www.kaiko.com/) has data for over 500 crypto tickers - although it can be expensive...

Answer (score 1):

[Quandl.com](https://www.quandl.com/search?query=bitcoin) offers volumes in addition to tick price data. This is, however, per exchange and not from day one of Bitcoin's inception.

More references and links can be found in [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/54710/where-can-i-find-crypto-coin-data/54711#54711).

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](https://www.cryptoarchive.com.au) - quite some tick data available.