# Who give initial value to Bitcoin?

Tags: api, exchange-rate, market, currencies

I know how the process of changing BTC price ​​occur, but I curious as to what gave the  initial value to BTC and whether the price of another cryptocurrency refers to the BTC?

How would I replicate this process using an API or any algorithm?

Comment: You're asking two things in a single question. Please try to split it into two separate questions, one asking about the initial price and the other one looking for APIs.

Comment: I (and another editor) condensed the two questions into one, and wonder if it can be reopened in its current form.

Comment: I am still not sure what this question is asking. It might be a duplicate to [Where do bitcoins come from and what gives them their value?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/182/5406), yet on the other hand seems to be asking [Where can I get historic data series of Bitcoin prices?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/748/5406) as well, and something else entirely. So, there are three close reasons: Multiple questions, intelligibility, and being a duplicate. It would really help if the asker were to clarify what he actually wants, but as it is it should stay closed, actually better deleted.

Comment: If you feel it is worth the effort to expand the discussion of this question's worth, please create a post on [meta] and link it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How much would you pay for 1 BTC in 2009 before knowing all this? Probably some cents since u would not mind losing, that was how the first BTC price was defined.

Nowadays is pure especulation with some basis on the price of electricity cost to generate 1 BTC.

APIs u can search for on the major exchanges, such as Bitstamp,BTCchina,Huobi,OKcoin,BTCe and so on...

Comment: Whoops, seems I misunderstood completely

Comment: You didn't. The asker made 2 questions in one.

Answer (score 0):

฿ price comes from whichever API you use. I prefer Coindesk because it does a weighted average, but Blockchain.info is another good option, as is Bitstamp or Coindesk.

From there you can use Bittrex API or Cryptsy or Poloniex.

There's also specialist API like [gem.io](http://gem.io) or [blockcypher.com](http://blockcypher.com)

Comment: OK, now I perhaps see the author's reference to "API", but it's still very inaccurate. API is not **where the price comes from**. The price comes from the market, it's where the demand and supply meet. That's the "source" of what is referred to as Bitcoin price. Now, API here is just an convenient access to **one** exchange's historical data, and does not have anything to do with the price forming process; thus I think it does not really fit into the topic of this question.