# All CryptoCurrency historical values api

Tags: api, currencies, charts, historical-trade-data

I am making a cryptocurrencies tracker and I want to implement a Chart. The only thing i need is a api that has the values of a lot of cryptocurrencies. Does anybody know a api like that? Please help

Comment: related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/748/where-can-i-get-historic-data-series-of-bitcoin-prices