# Tick and price data

Tags: historical-trade-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find a graph of Bitcoin value vs USD for over 60 days?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/136/where-can-i-find-a-graph-of-bitcoin-value-vs-usd-for-over-60-days)
>   [Where can I get raw data series of Bitcoin prices?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/748/where-can-i-get-raw-data-series-of-bitcoin-prices)

Where can I get historical price data for bitcoin?  I know the Apis will give me current data
, but what if I want the day's ticks for say 100 days ago?

Comment: Then again, on second thought I suspect you want data points in a convenient format, and not a chart ... so I'm sorry I voted to close. Here's a +1 for you.

Comment: There's also this question: [Where can I get raw data series of Bitcoin prices?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/748/where-can-i-get-raw-data-series-of-bitcoin-prices), which looks like a duplicate to me. @Cliff, do you agree?